# Is there something like vkCmdBlitImage for D3D12?

Tags: graphics, mipmaps, vulkan, direct3d12

I'd like to create a mipmap chain for a 2D texture by blitting the base image into mip levels. In Vulkan, `vkCmdBlitImage` can be used to do this while linearly filtering the image (see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37772540/generating-mipmaps-in-vulkan)). How can I achieve the same in D3D12?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Afaik D3D12 has no such functionality and you're supposed to generate the mip map chain with a compute shader like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/Shaders/GenerateMipsCS.hlsli) one from the MiniEngine in the DX samples provided by MS.

Comment: This is in the case you want a runtime surface with a mip chain. It is highly recommended to compress texture to BC format and generating mips offline allow better algorithms on them, like sharpening, proper wrapping and re-normalisation for normal maps.

Comment: The [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/) includes code for generating mipmap chains using shaders.